Type narrowing in list of assertions
I'm trying to combine a list of assertions in a type-safe way without having to call them all manually.
Example code:
type Base = { id: string, name?: string, age?: number };
type WithName = { name: string };
type WithAge = { age: number };

export type Asserter<T, U> = (x: T) => asserts x is T & U;

const assertName: Asserter<Base, WithName> = (x: Base): asserts x is Base & WithName => {
    if (x.name === undefined) {
        throw new Error("missing name");
    }
};

const assertAge: Asserter<Base, WithAge> = (x: Base): asserts x is Base & WithAge => {
    if (x.age === undefined) {
        throw new Error("missing age");
    }
};

type ExtractAssertions<T, U extends Asserter<T, any>[]> = 
    U extends [Asserter<T, infer V>, ...infer Rest]
        ? Rest extends Asserter<T, any>[]
            ? V & ExtractAssertions<T, Rest>
            : V
        : {};

function multiAssert<T, A extends Asserter<T, any>[]>(
  item: T,
  assertions: A
): asserts item is T & ExtractAssertions<T, A> {
  assertions.forEach(assertion => assertion(item));
}

const data: Base = { id: "aas-aa", name: "frank", age: 30 };

multiAssert(data, [assertName, assertAge]);

console.log(data.name[0]); // This should compile correctly
console.log(data.age + 3); // This should also be possible

I'm doing something wrong in the ExtractAssertions type, but I can't figure it out for the life of me.
Here's a link to a TS playground
I've tried a lot of variations on the recursive ExtractAssertions type, but they all either ended up back at the Base type, or led to never.

• Please consider [edit]ing to use conventional names; custom types should be in UpperCamelCase like Base; generic type names are generally short like A instead of Assertions, so they can be easily seen as generic. • Your problem is only that calling multiAssert() infers a too-wide type for assertions; you can fix that by using a const type parameter as shown in this playground. Does that fully address the q? If so I'll write an a; if not, what's missing?

That perfectly answers the question, thanks a lot. I've edited the code as you suggested. I adore the Typescript system, but there's a lot of things to learn that you need to kind of read between the lines for in the official documentation. I've yet to find a better holistic source.

Your ExtractAssertions type is fine (although you can likely get it to work without being a recursive conditional type). The problem seems to be that when you call multiAssert(), the type of assertions and therefore A is inferred too widely for your purposes and is just an unordered array type. But you want it to be a tuple type so it feeds into ExtractAssertions as intended.
You can affect this inference by making A a const type parameter, which gives TypeScript a hint that you want narrower inference:
function multiAssert<T, const A extends Asserter<T, any>[]>(
    item: T,
    assertions: A
): asserts item is T & ExtractAssertions<T, A> {
    assertions.forEach(assertion => assertion(item));
}

And now it works as intended:
const data: Base = { id: "aas-aa", name: "frank", age: 30 };    
multiAssert(data, [assertName, assertAge]);
// ^? function multiAssert<Base, [Asserter<Base, WithName>, Asserter<Base, WithAge>]>(⋯)
data
//^? const data: Base & WithName & WithAge

Playground link to code
